# Finding a string in a phrase

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I am using `regexpi` to find a string in a phrase. But I also encountered with something different which I never intended.

Let's say the words I need to find are `anandalak` and `nandaki`.

```
str1 = {'anandalak'};
str2 = {'nanda'};
button = {'nanda'};
```

Both of the following return me logical 1:

```
~cellfun('isempty',regexpi(str1,button))
~cellfun('isempty',regexpi(str2,button))
```

How can I avoid this? I need logical 0 in first case and logical 1 in the second.

Comment: So you want `logical 0` in first case and `logical 1` in the second. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: exactly, I need the one you described

Comment: use `strcmp`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use the [**word-boundaries(`\<\>`)**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in order to get the match which you require.

You may try:

```
str1 = {'anandalak'}
str2 = {'nanda'}
button = {'\<nanda\>'} % Notice this 
~cellfun(@isempty,regexpi(str1,button)) % Returns ans = 0 No match
~cellfun(@isempty,regexpi(str2,button)) % Return ans = 1 Exact match
```

You can find the sample run result of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/288L)